# Рекурсия в Java: почему не отрабатывается return?

Tags: java, ооп, рекурсия

`addChild` добавляет объект в `HashSet`, нахождение объекта в коллекции говорит о том, что он является ребенком объекта, вызавшевого метод:

```
a.addChild (b);
b.addChild (c);
```

`findChild` рекурсивно ищет ребенка по полю data:

[image: Скриншот]

**Собственно, сам вопрос.** После 1 иттерации  поле метода data совпадает полем data искомого объекта. **Почему не отрабатывает return и выполнение идет дальше?**

```
public TreeNode findChild (Object data) {
        Iterator<TreeNode> iterator = getChildrenIterator ();

        TreeNode node;
        while (iterator.hasNext ()) {
            node = iterator.next ();
            if (node.getData ()==data) {
                return node;
            }
            node.findChild (data);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверяйте результат вызовов `node.findChild`:

```
TreeNode result = node.findChild(data);
if (result != null)
  return result;
```

Comment: Все еще не работает. В какую часть кода добавлять проверку?              [shot](https://i.imgur.com/20niShM.png)

Comment: в строчку  `node.findChild (data);`